How to get stable collisions using verlet intergration?
I have been working on this simple physics system for a while and i originaly started with euler physics but couldn't manage to get stable collisions working and after switching to verlet integration i still cant get anything stable. It works completely fine when there is not enough balls to stack on top of each other but as soon as i add more balls and they land ontop of eachother they start flying off and its chaotic. you can see the full code and just the specific collision function below and im using C++ and sfml.
    // Collision check
    void checkCollisions(std::vector<Ball>& balls, std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<Ball*>>>& grid, int gridWidth, int gridHeight, int cellSize) {
        const float damping = 0.8f;
        const float epsilon = 0.001f;
        const float separationFactor = 1.01f; // Slight increase in separation
        const int collisionIterations = 5; // Number of iterations for collision resolution

        int cellX = static_cast<int>(position.x) / cellSize;
        int cellY = static_cast<int>(position.y) / cellSize;

        for (int iteration = 0; iteration < collisionIterations; ++iteration) {
            // Check neighboring cells for potential collisions
            for (int x = std::max(0, cellX - 1); x <= std::min(gridWidth - 1, cellX + 1); ++x) {
                for (int y = std::max(0, cellY - 1); y <= std::min(gridHeight - 1, cellY + 1); ++y) {
                    for (auto* otherBall : grid[x][y]) {
                        if (otherBall == this) continue;
                        float minDist = radius + otherBall->radius;
                        float dx = position.x - otherBall->position.x;
                        float dy = position.y - otherBall->position.y;
                        float distance = std::sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

                        if (distance < minDist && distance > epsilon) {
                            float nx = dx / distance;
                            float ny = dy / distance;

                            // Calculate relative velocity
                            float relativeVelocityX = (position.x - oldPosition.x) - (otherBall->position.x - otherBall->oldPosition.x);
                            float relativeVelocityY = (position.y - oldPosition.y) - (otherBall->position.y - otherBall->oldPosition.y);
                            float relativeVelocityDotNormal = relativeVelocityX * nx + relativeVelocityY * ny;

                            // Only proceed with collision resolution if balls are moving towards each other
                            if (relativeVelocityDotNormal < 0) {
                                float overlap = minDist - distance;
                                float moveDistance = overlap / 2.0f * separationFactor; // Slight increase in separation

                                // Move balls apart along the collision normal
                                position.x += nx * moveDistance;
                                position.y += ny * moveDistance;
                                otherBall->position.x -= nx * moveDistance;
                                otherBall->position.y -= ny * moveDistance;

                                // Calculate velocities
                                float v1x = position.x - oldPosition.x;
                                float v1y = position.y - oldPosition.y;
                                float v2x = otherBall->position.x - otherBall->oldPosition.x;
                                float v2y = otherBall->position.y - otherBall->oldPosition.y;

                                // Calculate normal velocity
                                float vn = (v2x - v1x) * nx + (v2y - v1y) * ny;

                                // Calculate impulse scalar
                                float impulse = (2.0f * vn) / (1.0f + 1.0f); // Assuming equal mass balls

                                // Apply impulse to change velocities
                                oldPosition.x -= impulse * nx * damping;
                                oldPosition.y -= impulse * ny * damping;
                                otherBall->oldPosition.x += impulse * nx * damping;
                                otherBall->oldPosition.y += impulse * ny * damping;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (distance <= epsilon) {
                            // Randomly perturb positions to prevent sticking
                            float perturbation = minDist - epsilon;
                            float angle = static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX * 2.0f * M_PI;
                            position.x += std::cos(angle) * perturbation / 2.0f;
                            position.y += std::sin(angle) * perturbation / 2.0f;
                            otherBall->position.x -= std::cos(angle) * perturbation / 2.0f;
                            otherBall->position.y -= std::sin(angle) * perturbation / 2.0f;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

and here is the full code just incase:
#include <cmath>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // for rand()
#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif

// Define the Vector2 class
class Vector2 {
public:
    float x;
    float y;

    // Add a default constructor
    Vector2() : x(0), y(0) {}

    // Add a constructor that takes x and y as arguments
    Vector2(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    // Define vector operations
    Vector2 operator+(const Vector2& other) const {
        Vector2 result;
        result.x = x + other.x;
        result.y = y + other.y;
        return result;
    }

    Vector2 operator-(const Vector2& other) const {
        Vector2 result;
        result.x = x - other.x;
        result.y = y - other.y;
        return result;
    }

    Vector2 operator*(float scalar) const {
        Vector2 result;
        result.x = x * scalar;
        result.y = y * scalar;
        return result;
    }

    Vector2 operator/(float scalar) const {
        Vector2 result;
        result.x = x / scalar;
        result.y = y / scalar;
        return result;
    }

    float length() const {
        return std::sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    Vector2 normalize() const {
        float len = length();
        if (len > 0) {
            return Vector2(x / len, y / len);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    float dot(const Vector2& other) const {
        return x * other.x + y * other.y;
    }
};

// Ball class
class Ball {
private:
    sf::CircleShape shape;
    Vector2 oldPosition;
    Vector2 acceleration;
    Vector2 gravity = Vector2(0, 980);
    float radius;

public:
    Vector2 position;

    Ball(float radius, sf::Color color, float x, float y)
        : radius(radius), position(x, y), oldPosition(x, y), acceleration(0, 0) {
        shape.setRadius(radius);
        shape.setFillColor(color);
        shape.setPosition(x - radius, y - radius);
    }

    void updatePhysics(float dt) {
        gravity.y = 980;
        Vector2 velocity = (position - oldPosition) / dt; // Calculate velocity
        oldPosition = position;
        position = position + velocity * dt + acceleration * (0.5f * dt * dt);
        acceleration = gravity; // Apply gravity

        // Threshold values
        const float restThreshold = 0.1f; // Lower threshold for resting
        const float minMovement = 0.01f; // Minimum movement threshold

        // Prevent jittering when at rest at bottom of window
        if (std::abs(velocity.y) < restThreshold && position.y + radius >= 600) {
            position.y = 600 - radius;
            acceleration.y = 0;
            gravity.y = 0;
            oldPosition.y = position.y;
        }

        // Bounce off the top of the window
        if (position.y - radius < 0) {
            position.y = radius;
            velocity.y = -velocity.y * 0.9f; // Dampen the bounce and invert the velocity
            oldPosition.y = position.y - velocity.y * dt;
        }

        // Bounce off the bottom of the window
        if (position.y + radius > 600) {
            position.y = 600 - radius;
            velocity.y = -velocity.y * 0.9f; // Dampen the bounce and invert the velocity
            oldPosition.y = position.y - velocity.y * dt;
        }

        // Bounce off the sides of the window
        if (position.x - radius < 0) {
            position.x = radius;
            velocity.x = -velocity.x * 0.7f; // Dampen the bounce and invert the velocity
            oldPosition.x = position.x - velocity.x * dt;
        }
        else if (position.x + radius > 1000) {
            position.x = 1000 - radius;
            velocity.x = -velocity.x * 0.7f; // Dampen the bounce and invert the velocity
            oldPosition.x = position.x - velocity.x * dt;
        }

        shape.setPosition(position.x - radius, position.y - radius);
    }

    // Collision check
    void checkCollisions(std::vector<Ball>& balls, std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<Ball*>>>& grid, int gridWidth, int gridHeight, int cellSize) {
        const float damping = 0.8f;
        const float epsilon = 0.001f;
        const float separationFactor = 1.01f; // Slight increase in separation
        const int collisionIterations = 5; // Number of iterations for collision resolution

        int cellX = static_cast<int>(position.x) / cellSize;
        int cellY = static_cast<int>(position.y) / cellSize;

        for (int iteration = 0; iteration < collisionIterations; ++iteration) {
            // Check neighboring cells for potential collisions
            for (int x = std::max(0, cellX - 1); x <= std::min(gridWidth - 1, cellX + 1); ++x) {
                for (int y = std::max(0, cellY - 1); y <= std::min(gridHeight - 1, cellY + 1); ++y) {
                    for (auto* otherBall : grid[x][y]) {
                        if (otherBall == this) continue;
                        float minDist = radius + otherBall->radius;
                        float dx = position.x - otherBall->position.x;
                        float dy = position.y - otherBall->position.y;
                        float distance = std::sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

                        if (distance < minDist && distance > epsilon) {
                            float nx = dx / distance;
                            float ny = dy / distance;

                            // Calculate relative velocity
                            float relativeVelocityX = (position.x - oldPosition.x) - (otherBall->position.x - otherBall->oldPosition.x);
                            float relativeVelocityY = (position.y - oldPosition.y) - (otherBall->position.y - otherBall->oldPosition.y);
                            float relativeVelocityDotNormal = relativeVelocityX * nx + relativeVelocityY * ny;

                            // Only proceed with collision resolution if balls are moving towards each other
                            if (relativeVelocityDotNormal < 0) {
                                float overlap = minDist - distance;
                                float moveDistance = overlap / 2.0f * separationFactor; // Slight increase in separation

                                // Move balls apart along the collision normal
                                position.x += nx * moveDistance;
                                position.y += ny * moveDistance;
                                otherBall->position.x -= nx * moveDistance;
                                otherBall->position.y -= ny * moveDistance;

                                // Calculate velocities
                                float v1x = position.x - oldPosition.x;
                                float v1y = position.y - oldPosition.y;
                                float v2x = otherBall->position.x - otherBall->oldPosition.x;
                                float v2y = otherBall->position.y - otherBall->oldPosition.y;

                                // Calculate normal velocity
                                float vn = (v2x - v1x) * nx + (v2y - v1y) * ny;

                                // Calculate impulse scalar
                                float impulse = (2.0f * vn) / (1.0f + 1.0f); // Assuming equal mass balls

                                // Apply impulse to change velocities
                                oldPosition.x -= impulse * nx * damping;
                                oldPosition.y -= impulse * ny * damping;
                                otherBall->oldPosition.x += impulse * nx * damping;
                                otherBall->oldPosition.y += impulse * ny * damping;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (distance <= epsilon) {
                            // Randomly perturb positions to prevent sticking
                            float perturbation = minDist - epsilon;
                            float angle = static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX * 2.0f * M_PI;
                            position.x += std::cos(angle) * perturbation / 2.0f;
                            position.y += std::sin(angle) * perturbation / 2.0f;
                            otherBall->position.x -= std::cos(angle) * perturbation / 2.0f;
                            otherBall->position.y -= std::sin(angle) * perturbation / 2.0f;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window) {
        window.draw(shape);
    }
};

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1000, 600), "Verlet Integration");
    std::vector<Ball> balls;
    const int ballNum = 20;
    const int Maxradius = 20;
    const int Minradius = 20;

    balls.reserve(ballNum);

    // Initialize balls
    for (int i = 0; i < ballNum; i++) {
        balls.emplace_back(rand() % Maxradius + Minradius, sf::Color(rand() % 255, rand() % 255, rand() % 255), rand() % 1000, rand() % 600);
    }

    // Grid parameters
    int gridWidth = 1000 / (Maxradius * 2);
    int gridHeight = 600 / (Maxradius * 2);
    int cellSize = 2 * Maxradius;

    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<Ball*>>> grid(gridWidth, std::vector<std::vector<Ball*>>(gridHeight));

    sf::Clock displayClock;
    sf::Clock physicsClock;
    float physicsDt = 1.0f / 240.0f;
    float physicsAccumulator = 0.0f;

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        float frameTime = displayClock.restart().asSeconds();
        physicsAccumulator += frameTime;

        // Physics update loop
        while (physicsAccumulator >= physicsDt) {
            // Clear grid
            for (auto& column : grid) {
                for (auto& cell : column) {
                    cell.clear();
                }
            }

            // Update ball positions
            for (auto& ball : balls) {
                ball.updatePhysics(physicsDt);

                int cellX = static_cast<int>(ball.position.x) / cellSize;
                int cellY = static_cast<int>(ball.position.y) / cellSize;
                if (cellX >= 0 && cellX < gridWidth && cellY >= 0 && cellY < gridHeight) {
                    grid[cellX][cellY].push_back(&ball);
                }
            }

            // Resolve collisions
            for (auto& ball : balls) {
                ball.checkCollisions(balls, grid, gridWidth, gridHeight, cellSize);
            }

            physicsAccumulator -= physicsDt;
        }

        // Clear window
        window.clear(sf::Color::White);

        // Draw balls
        for (auto& ball : balls) {
            ball.draw(window);
        }

        // Display frame
        window.display();

        // Ensure consistent frame rate
        sf::sleep(sf::seconds(1.0f / 60.0f) - displayClock.getElapsedTime());
    }

    return 0;
}


I have tried a bunch of tweaking to the dampening and this is what seems to work best but other then that im not sure what else i can do.

Why did you define your own vector class instead of using sf::Vec2f?

Few suggestions: when doing complex calculations, better to first do it on paper. Try to come up with an elegant solution on paper (simple to use equations) and use available tools (SFML classes). Put each step as comment in code, it will help you and others. Use custom data structures (vector of vector of vector of ... looks scary).

@kiner_shah thats a good idea, im still very new to programing and this is all new to me but this makes sense so thanks! ill do it to try figure out a better way this time and also for every project in the future

@Botje I didnt know they existed lol i definetly need to look into it though it sounds super helpful
